# Winform size changes

Tags: winforms, size, monitor

When i run the EXE of winforms it runs perfectly in 14 inch monitors , but it rearranges and the contents shrink and look bad when i run the same EXE in 12 inch monitors.

Has .NET Exes have some issues with the monitor size?

Please help me.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with resolution, not monitor size.

Bad behaviour when the form is resized means whoever designed it screwed up - nothing to do with .NET.